# Aplicar Border-bottom no link mas não na imagem

Tags: css, image, pseudo-classes

Estou com um problema que parece simples, mas não encontrei solução.
Eu criei um estilo de link que, em vez de ter um text-decoration underline, eu quero uma borda embaixo.

O problema é que se uma imagem tem um link, eu quero remover a borda.

Estou tentando esse código, mas a pseudo-classe `:not`, não está sendo aplicada à imagem, então tenho uma imagem com borda embaixo toda vez que insiro link nela.

```css
.post-body a:not(img) {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.post-body a img {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-body">
  <a href="#">
  Link
  </a>
</div>
<br /> Imagem sem link:
<div class="post-body">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/200x150" />
</div>
Imagem com link:
<div class="post-body">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/200x150" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Como aplicar a borda somente aos links e não às imagens+links utilizando CSS?

Comment: Já atualizei...

Comment: Já adianto que `a:not(img)` não funciona porque o seletor diz "uma tag `a` que não seja uma tag `img`", porém obviamente nenhuma `a` será `img`.

Comment: Hmm, entendi. Mas então seria impossível aplicar um estilo para um link que não fosse imagem, nem de outra maneira?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível. Basta você colocar uma classe na tag `a` onde você não quer borda e adicionar essa classe no `:not()`:

```css
.post-body a:not(.semborda) {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-body">
  <a href="#">
  Link
  </a>
</div>
<br /> Imagem sem link:
<div class="post-body">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/200x150" />
</div>
Imagem com link e sem borda:
<div class="post-body">
  <a href="#" class="semborda">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/200x150" />
  </a>
</div>
```